# Reinforcement Learning textbook or online resources

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Dear respected members,

I would like to cover RL in my data analystics course and I am searching for the best resource for students. Do you have any recommendations on textbooks or online resources that benefit students in learning RL?
Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite resources were

- [Sutton & Barto's book](http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/the-book.html)
  The 1st edition was the standard textbook, and the 2nd edition is recently updated (2020). Sutton hosts the complete PDF on his website.
- David Silver has full video lectures available on YouTube. Here is [the first one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pWv7GOvuf0) and [this playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqYmG7hTraZCRwoyGxvQkqVrZgDQi4m-5) has them in order.

One caveat: it's been I while since I studied the topic, I wouldn't know about recent resources.